# Journey builder and JobIDs

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, content-builder, jobid

I have a journey that used to send an email built in classic content, we genereated reports for each send based on JobID. In November we moved the email over to content builder and since then each time it has sent it has used the same JobID, which has messed our reporting up. Is this the way Journey builder works with content builder emails? If I wanted to generate a different JobID for each send what would I need to do?

Thank you

Comment: For all triggered emails, they utilize the same JobID until you pause and restart them. Generating a unique JobID for every individual triggered send is, pardon my bluntness, quite absurd.  If you want to track individual sends, you can check your send log or the data views utilizing the TriggeredSendID and SubscriberKey/SubscriberID.

Comment: Thanks for this, confirms what I suspected. I personally don't want to generate new JobIDs for each send, but that was the what was put to me by people above me so I at least had to ask.

Comment: @Gortonington how do we connect the TriggeredSendId with the journey? I can't find that referenced anywhere in the tracking or email.

Answer (score 2):

For all triggered emails, they utilize the same JobID until you pause and restart them. Generating a unique JobID for every individual triggered send is, pardon my bluntness, quite absurd. If you want to track individual sends, you can check your send log or the data views utilizing the TriggeredSendID and SubscriberKey/SubscriberID

In order to track the journey email sends, you would need to use the [_Journey Data View](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_journey.htm&type=5) to grab the VersionID of the Journey you want (if you do not already have it) and then use that VersionID to match on VersionID in [_JourneyActivity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_journey_activity.htm&type=5) Data View. This will allow you to grab the `JourneyActivityObjectID` which will match `TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID` in the other data views.

> JourneyActivityObjectID corresponds to TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
>   in the _Sent, _Open, _Click, _Bounce, and _Unsubscribe data views.

This will then let you create reporting on the Journey emails inside your Journies same as you would with any other Triggered Send Definition.